# Can anyone make sense of my electronics instructor's common emitter design?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, npn, common-emitter

I think that I need to give a little back story, but I will try to make it short enough as possible. I have a 2 year degree that I describe as half hardware/ half software. What I mean by that is half electronics design and half programming and controls. I work in a field that uses the programming and controls skills, but try to keep up with the hardware side via hobbies. Anyway, I am going through some old notes and refreshing myself on them (this class was roughly 2 years ago). When I get to the section of analog amplifiers, I am lost on how my instructor came up with the design. He taught us what he calls the "Quick and Dirty" method of CE design. This uses some odd values such as "r`e" and "re", neither of which are RE (emitter resistance.) I am including screen shots of a spreadsheet that I made of the formulas that we were given in class to design CE amplifiers, a close up of the formulas that I can't understand where they came from, and a schematic that I made in gschem from the values given by running the formulas in the spreadsheet.

I found an old test in which I gave these answers and got 100% on it. So in his opinion, this is correct. We also did physically build these in class. I have the components to build this now, but no oscilloscope to verify.

So my questions are.

1. What are the "r`e" and "re" values and does anyone have any idea where they came from? I tried Duckduckgoing these and the only thing that I could find is emitter resistance (which as I said is neither of these values.)
2. Does anyone have any critiques or criticisms of this design method?
3. Can anyone recommend an excellent resource for learning proper CE and other analog circuit design?

[image: This is the close up of the formulas in question.]

[image: This is the spreadsheet that I have made of the formulas.]

[image: Schematic]

Comment: (1) \$r_e\$ (called r`e in your sheet) is a local slope (in the sense of \$r_e=\frac{\textrm{d}V}{\textrm{d}I}\$) of the V-I curve of \$V_{BE}\$ vs \$I_E\$. It's easy to use calculus to show that \$r_e=\frac{k\: T}{q\: I_E}\approx \frac{26\:\textrm{mV}}{I_E}\$ at room temps. It's more important when \$V_E\$ is close to ground. In your case, \$V_E=1\:\textrm{V}\$, so not so important. (2) None I want to offer right now. (3) The Art of Electronics, v2, and its Student Manual or else The Art of Electronics, v3, and Learning the Art of Electronics.

Comment: What you have is a formulaic approach and it doesn't explain anything. I've no interest at all in discussing the criticizing such an approach -- since its focus is on just following a recipe. But the books I mentioned provide you with your own thinking process, so that you can not only understand that recipe but could make up a different one on your own, as well. They also cover a lot more. So that's also good.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your input. I think that the Art of Electronics is right up my alley. Just skimmed through the 9th chapter for free on their website.

Comment: It's a great text and I think targeted at self-learners as well as a textbook for a class. Seriously good. v2 was 1989 and v3 just came out about a year ago. The authors kept promising, but finally put all the huge energy needed and did it (I wrote to Dr. Hill many times.) I think we all owe them a great debt for the life's blood they offered us. Good people, those two. But the student book is IMPORTANT. With v2, that's what it is called. With v3, they renamed it to "Learning The Art of Electronics." It's still the student manual. And very necessary to fill in where the book leaves off.

Comment: FWIW, when analyzing circuits, parameters annotated with uppercase letters typically represent DC parameters--e.g., hFE is DC current gain, while parameters having lowercase letters represent AC parameters--e.g., hfe is AC current gain. So r'e is an AC parameter. And as @jonk has already mentioned, a good textbook on transistor circuits can explain all this stuff.

Comment: Both of you are jogging my memory a lot. I am looking to refresh/advance my electronics educations without spending a ton of money/time going to university. Looks like "Art of Electronics" is going to be a good stepping stone for that. Thank you.